# JavaScriptのprototype

Tags: javascript

```
function person(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.prof = function(){
    console.log("name : " + this.name + "\nage : " + this.age + "\ncolor : "+ this.color + "\nweight : " + this.weight);
  }
}
person.prototype.color = "red";
person.prototype.age = "18";

var man = new person("Jackbow");
man.weight = 50;
man.prof();
```

---

この `man.weight = 50;` を

```
man = {
  weight : 50
};
```

にしてはいけないのはなぜですか？

Comment: `new person(...)`で作ったオブジェクトを別のオブジェクトで上書きすることになるから（`man.prof();` が機能しなくなるため）。

Answer (score 5):

```
{
  weight : 50
}
```

この文で `weight` プロパティだけを持ったオブジェクトを作っています。このオブジェクトは `man` とも `person` とも無関係です。ですから、

```
man = {
  weight : 50
};
```

と書いてしまうと、その新しいオブジェクトで `man` の中身を丸ごと置き換えてしまいます。

```
man.weight = 50;
```

と書いた場合は `weight` プロパティだけが変更されるため、他のプロパティや、プロトタイプチェインに影響を与えることはありません。